# assembly.GetTypes() and GetExportedTypes() does not return all public objects

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I am trying to get some plugin stuff to work in asp.net mvc. My plugin DLL has a controller as well as a descriptor/module class.

The controller signature looks like this:

```
[Export("SomeController", typeof(System.Web.Mvc.IController))]
[PartCreationPolicy(System.ComponentModel.Composition.CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class SomeController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{ }
```

and the module descriptor class has the following signature:

```
[Export("SomeModule", typeof(Plugins.IModule))]
[PartCreationPolicy(System.ComponentModel.Composition.CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class SomeModule : Plugins.IModule
{ }
```

Now this "plugin" assembly is dynamically loaded without problems. The issue arises when I use the GetTypes() and GetExportedTypes() methods:

```
private void GetModuleEntry(Assembly a) {
   IModule module = null;
   Type type = a.GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.GetInterface(typeof(IModule).Name) != null).FirstOrDefault();
   if (type != null) { do something }
   else { throw exception; }
}
```

So, the issue being that given the class signatures above, both the GetTypes() and GetExportedTypes() (without using the Where clause) return only the SomeController class. The SomeModule class is NEVER listed by either method! I have checked that my setting a breakpoint and calling the GetTypes() and GetExportedTypes() on the immediate command window prior to executing the next statement with the Where clause.

So why is that? why my module class is being left out even though it is a PUBLIC class and also has the Exported attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me; the code I tried inside an empty WinForms app shell is below.

If I had to guess at your problem, I believe it has to do with either:

**FirstOrDefault**: Is it possible the assembly that you look inside has two classes that implement IModule, and the first one found is not *SomeModule* but something different?  That's one way your code would never find *SomeModule*.

**The reference to IModule in GetModuleEntry**: Is it possible that in the project where you defined GetModuleEntry that you are referencing a newer or different version of the assembly that contains the interface IModule?  Unless the GetModuleEntry method is referencing the exact DLL that contains the definition of IModule referenced by the assembly containing SomeModule, you could run into problems.

I'm thinking the latter is the most likely, or will at least point you in the right direction to solving the problem.

Here is the test code that works fine, because there is only one class implementing IMyInterface (so FirstOrDefault is OK), and all classes/interfaces are in the same module:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{ }

public class bar
{ }

[Export("SomeController", typeof(bar))]
[PartCreationPolicy(System.ComponentModel.Composition.CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class foo : bar
{ }

[Export("SomeModule", typeof(IMyInterface))]
[PartCreationPolicy(System.ComponentModel.Composition.CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class ifoo : IMyInterface
{ }

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        Type type = a.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.GetInterface(typeof(IMyInterface).Name) != null).FirstOrDefault();

        if (type != null) // type is of Type ifoo
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success!"); 
        }

    }
}
```